# what libuv threadpool threads will do when they are not in use?

Tags: node.js, events, libuv

As per my understanding libuv threadpool's default size is 4 and it can be expanded up-to 128. my question is if the threads allocated as default size, what the other threads(124) will do? will it sleep? or engaged with some other event handling tasks?

Answer (score 0):

When the pool size is 4, really only 4 I/O threads are started, and not 128 (of which only 4 will be used).

The number 128 is the allowed maximum size of the pool, but libuv has to know at startup time how many threads it needs to allocate (and that number can, AFAIK, not change during the lifetime of the process).

Answer (score 0):

The threadpool's threads are all started the first time the threadpool is used.  The unused threads will be sleeping, waiting on a condition variable to wake them up.

The number of threads in the pool cannot be changed at runtime at the moment.